# how to use delegates inside a backgroundworker vb

Tags: vb.net, delegates

im using this code into a backgroundworker:

```
 iu(element.Element("link").Value, element.Element("delete").Value)
```

and the function is:

```
Private Sub iu(ByVal elo As String, ByVal elos As String)
        iudone.Show()
        iudone.TextBox1.Text = elo
        iudone.TextBox2.Text = elos
    End Sub
```

how i can use delegates to call iu() sub without exceptions?

the code executes a foreach elemt how shows elements and i want to show the element in another sub

Comment: Duplicate of [How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)

Comment: its different ,i need vb.net not c#

Comment: No it's not. `Invoke` and `Invoke` is the same in `c#` and `vb.net`. Here: `Me.Invoke(Sub() Me.iu(element.Element("link").Value, element.Element("delete").Value))`

Comment: i really dont know the use of delegates,i just want to show a new form with values without exceptions but i find that only with delegates it can be posibble

Comment: Then I suggest you start reading. The answer to your question is posted in the dupe link. I also gave you an example in my previous comment.